# Annoying bugs when using Chrome

Tags: bug, mathjax, google-chrome

After recent update of Google Chrome I got two following problems:

1. When I'm typing my answer every 3-5 minutes my browser crashes down and say that I had to refresh the page to return back. But after returning back I see that all the text and formulas are gone! The only workaround I know is every 3-5 minutes I had to save my notes in notepad. It is worth to mention that crashes occur only if I actively typing formulas, otherwise browsers page can "live" for a long time.
2. When I'm trying to watch formula typed by other users I just right click and choose Show Math As->TeX Commands. But after update nothing happens and there is no opened windows. Other tabs doesn't work also.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I agree with both the bugs. I am one of those "chosen" to be bugged by both of them. The first one annoys the hell out of  me...

Comment: @KannappanSampath and Norbert:  I have posted a userscript that I'm hoping will resolve this issue for you in [another answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4167/7798).  You might want to try it out and see if it prevents the crashes you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgraded to Chrome 18, there are a number of issues reported with that version, especially in Windows.  For your (2), see for example [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3901/mathjax-bugs-show-math-as-tex-commands-and-bold-math-in-comments), and [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115585) on the Chrome bug tracker.

For (1), can you report the exact error message that you receive, and explain further the details of the state the Chrome is in?  Does Chrome actually crash (do you get "Aw Snap"?  Or is it that the page is frozen?  Or is it something else?

Comment: I was getting both: composing any medium-length answer *always* causes the Chrome page to freeze. Also, I was getting "Aw Snaps" too, though I don't recall the context. I had to stop using Chrome here because I lost far too much work due to the crashes. It is *by far* the worst problem I've encountered since the site went public.

Comment: @Bill: what do you mean by saying that the site went public?

Comment: @Ilya SE sites start out in a private beta phase before they are opened to the general public.

Comment: @Bill: thanks for the clarification - I think MSE has gone public before I joined (15 months ago). I always had problem with Chrome while writing large answers (like freezing) - but 2 months ago or so things became much more worse. Chrome and MathJax started producing bugs with annoying frequency.

Comment: @Davide Cervone. I think I get "Aw, Snap!". In fact I use Russian version of Chrome so it shows me "Опаньки" page. I think this is the same as "Aw, Snap!" in English. As for details. After such crashes I had to refresh my page. And in a half of cases all the text that I wrote is lost. In another half of cases page restores at the same state it was before crashing.

Comment: @Ilya Yes, that's roughly the same time that Chrome became unusable for me too. It's unfortunate that the site no longer works with one of the leading browsers, since that may cause us to lose members.

Comment: @BillDubuque: which browser do you use now for MSE?

Comment: @Norbert "Опаньки" is indeed the same, was quite funny to see it for the first time :)

Comment: @Ilya, but now it is not funny at all. This bug makes me mad!

Comment: @Ilya Until the Chrome bugs are fixed I am using Firefox and IE. Both have issues (e.g. IE has bugs restoring sessions after a crash). I prefer Chrome because it is *much* faster on my systems, and its MathJax rendering looks nicer to me.

Comment: Note that Chrome occasionally has problems restoring sessions too, but there is an easy workaround. Simply copy the files "last X" to "current X" for X in {Tabs Session}. So, before this bug, by using Chrome, one could be guaranteed to *never* lose data, even for crashes. Alas, this MathJax bug destroys that nice property.

Comment: I have got several Aw! Snaps too while writing even answers of moderate size. The first bug, if it happens while first composing the answer, you are saved; but while editing, it is just inconvenience bundled with loss of time and energy. The freezing of chrome would be much better than the first bug Norbert reports.

Comment: @David I've posted a [new question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4037/242) on the Chrome MathJax crashes since I am forced to make decisions on browser choice etc. after waiting a couple months for a fix. Could you please refer the appropriate SE folks to that thread.